# How can I encrypt URL parameters in Android and decrypt with PHP?

Tags: java, php, android, http

I am doing an HTTP Post from Android like:

```
http://abc.com/whatis.php?user=abc@def.com&device=A123456789
```

PHP receives the request does what it is supposed to and sends the response back to Android.

It works as expected. But I want to encrypt the parameter values for `user=`  and `device=`  from my Android code and then transmit the request. On the other hand when the request is received at the server by the PHP, I want to decrypt the parameters and then do what the PHP is doing.

What would be a recommended method of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) or [javax.crypto](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) namespace for Java in Android

and in PHP you can use the [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) function

Make sure you use the SAME...

1. Cryptographic Algorithm
2. Mode of Operation
3. Key Size
4. Padding (Optionally)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about your data being decrypted you can use a own crypt algorithmic, since most users will not know what are your doing with those Strings.

An better way to do that is POST these parameters through the message body, and not in the URL. And if available, use a SSL connection.

Comment: Well I need to decrypt the data on the server side, thats for sure.

Comment: You has access to the Server Side implementation? If you do you can use the "own crypt" approach.

Comment: If he's not worried about the data being decrypted, why would he encrypt in the first place?

Comment: @Ranhiry Cooray : I don't know, this was his question.

Comment: POST by itself is not encrypted or in any way hardened. Anyone can intercept or create POST values almost as easily as GET values. Using SSL is required to make those values encrypted during transit and automatically unencrypted by the receiving server.

Comment: @Zimzat, yes the SSL is the better way to do that. The strange about the question is that he is doing an POST with a URL like a GET.

Comment: @Marcos: What I am referring to is, you specifying "If you are not worried about your data being decrypted". Why would he encrypt if he's not worried about the security? ;)

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with using GET parameters on a POST request. You just can't put a POST body on a GET request. Regarding the strangeness, maybe someone just needs to show him how to do a POST body in Android.

Comment: @Zimzat, sorry, I just expressed wrong, an own crypt algorithm can be decrypted by an experience user who really want to decrypt it and have to do, but in most cases, they will never do that.

Comment: @Marcos : That's considered security through obscurity, which is actually worse than no security in that it gives people a false sense of security.

Comment: This is why I say the better options is to use a SSL connection.